# API calls working locally but not through Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, heroku

I am running an app locally that posts data to a MongoDB database, it works fine when run locally, but as soon as I run it through Heroku it doesn't work and I am getting the below error message:

Any ideas where I could be going wrong?

```
"error": "Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms"

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// require database connection
const dbConnect = require("./db/dbConnect");
const User = require("./db/userModel"); // Import the User model

// execute database connection
dbConnect();

// Curb Cores Error by adding a header here
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});

// body parser configuration
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", (request, response, next) => {
  response.json({ message: "Hey! This is your server response!" });
  next();
});

// register endpoint
app.post("/register", (request, response) => {
  
      const user = new User({
        email: "beersdfne@gmail.com",
        password: "hello",
      });

      // save the new user
      user
        
      .save()
        
        // return success if the new user is added to the database successfully
      .then((result) => {
        response.status(201).send({
          message: "User Created Successfully",
          result,
        });
      })
        // catch error if the new user wasn't added successfully to the database
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
          response.status(500).send({
            message: "Error creating user",
            error: error.message,
          });
        });
    })

    // Endpoint to fetch the "hello" variable from the database

    app.get("/fetch", (request, response) => {
      // Use the User model to fetch data from the "test" collection
      User.findOne({}, { _id: 0, email: 0, password: 0 }) // Replace with the fields you want to retrieve
        .then((result) => {
          if (result) {
            response.status(200).send({
              message: "Data Fetched Successfully",
              data: result,
            });
          } else {
            response.status(404).send({
              message: "No data found",
            });
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error while fetching data:", error);
          response.status(500).send({
            message: "Error while fetching data",
            error: error.message,
          });
        });
    });
    

module.exports = app;

dbConnect.js - 

// external imports
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require('dotenv').config();

async function dbConnect() {
  // use mongoose to connect this app to our database on mongoDB using the DB_URL (connection string)
  mongoose
    .connect(
        process.env.DB_URL,
      {
        //   these are options to ensure that the connection is done properly
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
      })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB Atlas!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Unable to connect to MongoDB Atlas!");
      console.error(error);
    });
}


module.exports = dbConnect;

userModel.js

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please provide an Email!"],
        unique: [true, "Email Exist"],
      },
    
      password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please provide a password!"],
        unique: false,
      },
  })
  
  module.exports = mongoose.model.Users || mongoose.model("Users", UserSchema);
```

i tried working through the config vars, i added the connection string with and without quotation marks.

Comment: I'd add some debugging to your `dbConnect()` call and verify that you actually connected properly to your database.

Comment: That’s where the error is coming from